# How to use macport to install software?

Tags: macos, installation, macports

```
$ sudo port install linkchecker
--->  Computing dependencies for openssl
--->  Verifying checksum(s) for openssl
Error: No checksum set for openssl-1.0.0f.tar.gz
Error: Target org.macports.checksum returned: Unable to verify file checksums
Log for openssl is at: /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_svn.macports.org_trunk_dports_devel_openssl/main.log
Error: Unable to upgrade port: 1
Error: Unable to execute port: upgrade python27 failed
To report a bug, see <http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets>
```

It seems the port doesn't have a clean state to start with?

### [EDIT1] `sudo port -d selfupdate`

I'm behind a firewall which might not allow `rsync`.

```
$ sudo port -d selfupdate
Password:
--->  Updating the ports tree
DEBUG: Synchronizing ports tree(s)
Synchronizing local ports tree from file:///opt/local/var/macports/sources/svn.macports.org/trunk/dports/
DEBUG: /usr/bin/svn update --non-interactive /opt/local/var/macports/sources/svn.macports.org/trunk/dports
DEBUG: changing euid/egid - current euid: 0 - current egid: 0
U    /opt/local/var/macports/sources/svn.macports.org/trunk/dports/python/py-pyqt4/Portfile
U    /opt/local/var/macports/sources/svn.macports.org/trunk/dports/python/py-mhash/Portfile
U    /opt/local/var/macports/sources/svn.macports.org/trunk/dports/python/py-tweepy/Portfile
U    /opt/local/var/macports/sources/svn.macports.org/trunk/dports/python/py-pyttsx/Portfile
U    /opt/local/var/macports/sources/svn.macports.org/trunk/dports/python/py-docx/Portfile
U    /opt/local/var/macports/sources/svn.macports.org/trunk/dports/python/py-clint/Portfile
 U   /opt/local/var/macports/sources/svn.macports.org/trunk/dports/gnome/gnucash-devel
Updated to revision 88813.
Creating port index in /opt/local/var/macports/sources/svn.macports.org/trunk/dports
Adding port aqua/Readown
Failed to parse file archivers/arj/Portfile: invalid command name "get_canonical_archflags"
Failed to parse file archivers/gzip/Portfile: invalid command name "installs_libs"
Failed to parse file archivers/ucl/Portfile: invalid command name "get_canonical_archflags"
Failed to parse file archivers/unzip/Portfile: invalid command name "installs_libs"
Failed to parse file archivers/upx/Portfile: invalid command name "get_canonical_archflags"
Failed to parse file archivers/xdelta/Portfile: invalid command name "get_canonical_archflags"
Failed to parse file archivers/zip/Portfile: invalid command name "installs_libs"
Failed to parse file archivers/zoo/Portfile: invalid command name "get_canonical_archflags"
.
.
.
```

### [EDIT2] `sudo port clean --all openssl`

`sudo port clean --all openssl` didn't work.

```
$ sudo port install linkchecker
--->  Computing dependencies for openssl
--->  Verifying checksum(s) for openssl
Error: No checksum set for openssl-1.0.0f.tar.gz
Error: Target org.macports.checksum returned: Unable to verify file checksums
Log for openssl is at: /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_svn.macports.org_trunk_dports_devel_openssl/main.log
Error: Unable to upgrade port: 1
Error: Unable to execute port: upgrade python27 failed
To report a bug, see <http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets>
$ sudo port clean --all openssl
--->  Cleaning openssl
$ sudo port install linkchecker
--->  Computing dependencies for openssl
--->  Fetching openssl
--->  Attempting to fetch openssl-1.0.0f.tar.gz from http://www.openssl.org/source/
--->  Verifying checksum(s) for openssl
Error: No checksum set for openssl-1.0.0f.tar.gz
Error: Target org.macports.checksum returned: Unable to verify file checksums
Log for openssl is at: /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_svn.macports.org_trunk_dports_devel_openssl/main.log
Error: Unable to upgrade port: 1
Error: Unable to execute port: upgrade python27 failed
To report a bug, see <http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets>
$
```

### [EDIT3] tarball install also doesn't work

```
$ more /opt/local/etc/macports/sources.conf
#  MacPorts system wide sources configuration file
#  $Id: sources.conf 42662 2008-11-28 23:18:50Z raimue@macports.org $

<snip>   

#  To get the ports tree from the master MacPorts server in California, USA use:
#      rsync://rsync.macports.org/release/ports/
#  To get it from the mirror in Trondheim, Norway use:
#      rsync://trd.no.rsync.macports.org/release/ports/
#  A current list of mirrors is available at http://trac.macports.org/wiki/Mirrors
#rsync://rsync.macports.org/release/ports/ [default]
#http://www.macports.org/files/ports.tar.gz [default]
file:///opt/local/var/macports/sources/svn.macports.org/trunk/dports/ [default]
$ sudo vim /opt/local/etc/macports/sources.conf
$ sudo port -d sync
DEBUG: Synchronizing ports tree(s)
Synchronizing local ports tree from http://www.macports.org/files/ports.tar.gz
No updates for http://www.macports.org/files/ports.tar.gz
$ more /opt/local/etc/macports/sources.conf
$ sudo port install linkchecker
--->  Computing dependencies for openssl
--->  Fetching openssl
--->  Attempting to fetch openssl-1.0.0f.tar.gz from http://www.openssl.org/source/
--->  Verifying checksum(s) for openssl
Error: No checksum set for openssl-1.0.0f.tar.gz
Error: Target org.macports.checksum returned: Unable to verify file checksums
Log for openssl is at: /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_www.macports.org_files_ports_devel_openssl/main.log
Error: Unable to upgrade port: 1
Error: Unable to execute port: upgrade python27 failed
To report a bug, see <http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets>
```

Comment: Have you tried `sudo port -d selfupdate` to update the installed MacPorts infrastructure?

Comment: Consider doing what the comments [on this issue](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/16486) suggest.

Comment: Use [these instructions](http://trac.macports.org/wiki/howto/PortTreeTarball) instead to `selfupdate`.

Comment: I realize that this isn't really a direct answer, but you may want to try [Homebrew](http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/) instead.

Comment: I can actually use svn, is there a reason why I should use tar ball instead?

Comment: Thanks for reply. But my question was *NOT* something like "how to install softwares using package management systems for Mac OS X".

Comment: It's also for user *unable to use `rsync`*. Know anyone like that? It's simply the same solution for both problems...

Comment: This is odd. The [portfile](http://svn.macports.org/repository/macports/trunk/dports/devel/openssl/Portfile) contains the checksums.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have a corrupted Portfile: your openssl port doesn't have a *checksums* variable set.

The *clean --all* operation is not of any help because it cleans distfile (the actual archive for the port being built) and work directory, not the Portfile.

You can check if your current Portfile has checksums setting in it by running

```
port cat openssl | grep checksums ; echo $?
```

a **1** as output means Portfile is corrupted.

The easiest way to restore the file is deleting it and then resync, when on rsync or svn (I'm unsure about the single tarball). So switch back to svn in sources.conf, i.e. restore the *file:///* entry, and run:

```
sudo port -d sync; sudo rm $(port dir openssl)/Portfile; sudo port -d sync
```

The errors in **EDIT 2** means that your port command doesn't know about procedures used in portfiles, that is it's outdated. I'm not sure why *selfupdate* didn't update it.

Comment: I ended up reinstalling MacPorts.  I'll try this next time when I have the same issue.

Comment: You shouldn't have it again, but in case you do I suggest to investigate what's the real cause.